# Returning wrong data

Tags: meteor

I'm having a problem returning the correct `theSalary`. It returns the same salary for all the offers.

Path: `helpers.js`

```
Template.jobOfferCandidateView.helpers({
    jobOffers: ()=> {
        return JobOffers.find({candidateUserId: Meteor.userId()});
    },
    theSalary: function () {
        var jobOffers = JobOffers.findOne({});              
        var num = (jobOffers && jobOffers.salary) ? jobOffers.salary.toString() : '';

        return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
    }
});
```

Path: `template.html`

```
{{#each jobOffers}}

    {{title}}
    ${{theSalary}}

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theSalary` is called inside of an `{{#each jobOffers}}` loop, so its context is a job offer.

The first line of `theSalary` is currently:

```
var jobOffers = JobOffers.findOne({});
```

which just returns the first job offer in the collection (this is why you are always getting the same salary). Try changing that line to:

```
var jobOffers = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the `jobOffer`context inside the `each` block, you can just do something like:

```
theSalary: function () {
    num = '';

    if (this.salary !== undefined) {
        num = this.salary.toString();
    }

    return num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
},
```